# matching a string between 2 nth positions

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract the text between the 3rd and 4th slash from a url.

I have followed 2 or 3 posts on SO to achieve this and I can now select all slashes. But not targeting the 4th and 5th.

```
(?:[\/])
```

```
domain.com/dirone/dirtwo/prd/12345
```

However, I am trying to now select the 3rd and 4th slashes, using information from the posts.

```
(?:[\/]).{4}
```

But this selects 4 characters after every slash slash. Which is not what I need.

I understand from a very helpful post, once I can extract the slashes, I need something similar to this:

```
(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])
```

I am sure I am absolutely doing something nonsensical however, I am struggling to stitch together the intel from various posts to get even close to the success criteria.

Any advice would be very much welcomed.

Comment: A common way is to split the string at the slashes and take the part(s) you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the regex flavor supports variable length lookbehinds, you could use following regex:

```
(?<=(?:[^\/]+\/){3})[^\/]+(?=\/)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ReGppA/1/

- `(?<=(?:[^\/]+\/){3})` positive lookbehind, match 3 times some text and a slash
- `[^\/]+` the text between the 3th and 4th slash
- `(?=\/)` positive lookahead, the 4th slash

To match between 2nd and 3th:

```
(?<=^(?:[^\/]+\/){2})[^\/]+(?=\/)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zdyODD/1/

Comment: oh my, thank you, that works great and I am rather embarrassed to say. I have spent 20 minutes trying to adapt it and experiment with the syntax. May I ask, how would you modify the above to match between the 2nd and 3rd slash?

Comment: I am hacking away, I think I cracked it. ```(?<=(?:[^\/]+\/){2})[^\/]+(?=(?:[^\/]+\/){2}).```

Comment: I made an edit to match between 2nd and 3th slash.

Comment: Thank you @alex-dl you have been a great help!

Comment: Glad I could help.